# Where is the data type mismatch when passing arrays from vba to c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, vba, arguments

My C# COM DLL has a method that accepts a float array and a long int array. It returns a float.

From VBA in an MS Access module, I create an array of type single and another of type long, populate them, create the DLL app.class object and then call its method with the two arrays. But I get a "type mismatch" error.

The following is the actual code, but it is simple because I'm trying to work out the communications before adding the "real" code.

C# code:

```
public float JustTesting(float[] Array1, long[] Array2)
{
    return 96.0F;
}
```

VBA code:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim a1(0 To 0) As Single, a2(0 To 0) As Long, sng As Single
    a1(0) = 5
    a2(0) = 10
    Dim o As Variant
    Set o = CreateObject("MyApp.MyClass")
    sng = o.JustTesting(a1, a2)
    Debug.Print CStr(sng)
    Set o = Nothing
End Sub
```

Where is the data type mismatch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`Long`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164754.aspx) in VBA is only 32 bits, the same was as an `int` in C#.  So your method needs to take an array of `ints`

```
public float JustTesting(float[] Array1, int[] Array2)
{
    return 96.0F;
}
```